# Cassandra jmx metrics missing

Tags: cassandra

I have setup 2 cassandra clusters using identical setup procedure. Both the clusters are running without any issues.

But there is inconsistency in the way cassandra metrics being exposed via JMX.

The JMX exporter is setup using instructions mentioned [here](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-cassandra-with-prometheus).

Both the clusters export metrics, but on one of the cluster lesser metrics are being exposed.

To be more specific, metrics related to **cassandra_table_totaldisk** is missing on one, while its present on another.

```
#/etc/cassandra$ tail -1 cassandra-env.sh
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:/opt/prometheus- 
jmx/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:/etc/cassandra/cassandra-exporter-conf.yml"
#/etc/cassandra$ ls /opt/prometheus-jmx/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar
/opt/prometheus-jmx/jars/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar
#/etc/cassandra$ ls /etc/cassandra/cassandra-exporter-conf.yml
/etc/cassandra/cassandra-exporter-conf.yml
#/opt/prometheus-jmx/jars$ curl localhost:7070/metrics | grep cassandra_table_totaldisk | grep types
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6533k  100 6533k    0     0   716k      0  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:-- 1680k
cassandra_table_totaldiskspaceused{table="types",keyspace="system_schema",} 0.0
```

I have verified that the cassandra schema is present and keyspace table files are generated on the node.

What would cause this inconsistency?
How can I debug/ investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it turned out that, the matrices were not getting generated the way we want, because, cassandra was not getting restarted after the cassandra was configured for jmx-exporter.

The steps were automated using ansible script. The ansible role to restart cassandra was not getting called after jmx-exporter setup. The cause was [this ansible issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/34115). Once we ensured that cassandra is started only once (by ensuring that ansible role is called only once) and that is only after the jmx-exporter setup is done, the issue got resolved.

Comment: Hi, I am following the same tutorial but I am on Windows10 machine. Can you please see if you can answer this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65345430/unable-to-run-prometheus-on-windows-10-for-cassandra