# unable to run prometheus on windows 10 for Cassandra

Tags: windows, batch-file, cassandra, prometheus

I am following this tutorial to run `Prometheus` on `Windows10`. The tutorial is for `linux`. I suppose the only command I need to change is for `powershell`. However, when I try to access the metrics, the application doesn't connect.

https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-cassandra-with-prometheus

Instead of `echo 'JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:'$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:$PWD/cassandra.yml'"' >> conf/cassandra-env.sh`, I have added the following line in the `cassandra-env.ps1`

```
    # Default JMX setup, bound to local loopback address only
    $env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT"
    $env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS -javaagent:'$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:$PWD/cassandra.yml'"' <-- HERE

    $env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS $env:JVM_EXTRA_OPTS"
}
```

but `http://localhost:7070/metrics` doesn't work

UPDATE
Now, I have removed the changes from `.sh`. and `ps1` and add the `javaagent` only in `bin/cassanbra.bat` file as it seems that is what is required in Windows

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Apache+Cassandra+Startup+Settings

But Now I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:38)
        ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS -javaagent:'$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:$PWD/cassandra.yml'"'
```

try this:

```
$env:JVM_OPTS="$env:JVM_OPTS -javaagent:'$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:$PWD/cassandra.yml'"
```

I removed a single quote from the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it doesn't work. I believe the correct way to run is to change in .bat and not in .sh or .ps1 files as I was able to run https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-exporter by adding it in the .bat file.

Comment: @ManuChadha Can you share the portion of the .bat file that you changed?

Comment: `set JAVA_OPTS=-ea^
-javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar"^
-javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\cassandra-exporter-agent-0.9.10.jar"^
 <-HERE
`

Comment: If you would like to , please check this? I think if the path issue could be solved then the exporter might work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357086/convert-a-sh-command-into-bat-equivalent

Comment: I got it working.here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357086/convert-a-sh-command-into-bat-equivalent