# convert a .sh command into .bat equivalent

Tags: prometheus, jmx, jmx-exporter

I am following this tutorial to run jmx_exporter`with`cassandra`

https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-cassandra-with-prometheus

I have found that instead of changing `JVM_OPTS` in `cassandra-env.sh` file, I should change `bin/cassandra.bat` to make `javaagent` work (I tried adding `JVM_OPTS` in both `.sh` and `.ps1` but none worked)

https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Apache+Cassandra+Startup+Settings

The challenge I am facing is converting

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:'$PWD/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:$PWD/cassandra.yml'"'`

into equivalent in the `.bat` file

I have tried the following but none works

`-javaagent:"C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\apache-cassandra-3.11.6-for-scalardb\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:cassandra.yml"^`

and

`-javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:%CASSANDRA_HOME%\cassandra.yml"^`

I see error - `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Has anyone tried running `prometheus-jmx` on windows? Any tips on how I can solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using  path `javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:cassandra.yml"^`

But I can't do

`javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.0.jar=7070:%CASSANDRA_HOME%\cassandra.yml"^`

It seems I can't use `CASSANDRA_HOME` within a path